# What does "??" do in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I found this new and interesting code in my project. What does it do, and how does it work?

```
MemoryStream stream = null;
MemoryStream st = stream ?? new MemoryStream();
```

Comment: Hint its known as `Null Coalescing` operator

Comment: ?? operator chaekcs if stream is null if null then creates the new memorystream using new keyword .

Comment: it's the confusion operator

Comment: it is amazing how lazy peopele can be. Google query "?? operator" gives you an answer on first hit. Seriously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A ?? B
```

is a shorthand for

```
if (A == null) 
    B
else 
    A
```

or more precisely

```
A == null ? B : A
```

so in the most verbose expansion, your code is equivalent to:

```
MemoryStream st;
if(stream == null)
    st = new MemoryStream();
else
    st = stream;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means if `MemoryStream stream` equals `null`, create `MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();`

so in this case the following:

```
MemoryStream st = stream ?? new MemoryStream();
```

means

```
MemoryStream st;

if (stream == null)
   st = new MemoryStream();
else 
   st = stream;
```

It's called a **null coelesce operator**. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Ya, it working in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a null coalesce operator. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

It means that if `stream` is null, it will create a new `MemoryStream` object.